# Do molecular motors have a life time?

Tags: molecular-biology

Most of the enzymes have a certain lifetime. I want to know that do molecular motors have a certain lifetime after which they degenerate? Any reference will be appreciated.
Basically, I just want to model a molecular motor with a finite lifetime for that I need a certain numerical age span that they follow or maybe some exponential decay model.

Furthermore, as suggested by WYSIWYG I have got a particular term for the protein lifetime with which I can search. I will try to find the answer myself and post it.

Comment: All proteins have turnover. Even if they are not actively degraded they are at least reduced by half because of cell division. Can you please elaborate so that we can understand the rationale of your question better?

Comment: @WYSIWYG I just want to model a molecular motor with a finite lifetime for that I need a certain numerical age span that they follow or maybe some exponential decay model.

Comment: You should [edit] your question to add all the details instead of replying in comments. Comments are not searchable and even otherwise not easily noticed. Moreover, posts should be self sufficient. Anyway, your question is still very broad. There are several molecular motors in different cell types and there are different ways to model biochemical reactions. Did you try to search the literature (just Google "turnover rate of xxx")?